# Как сохранить изменения HTML над чужим сайтом в своем браузере после перезагрузки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сохранить изменения HTML на чужом сайте что бы **после перезагрузки** сайт грузился с изменёными настройками?
Или подскажите какие нибудь расширения для этого.

Comment: Взломать чужой сайт.

Comment: В чьем браузере? В своем или в чужом? Какие именно изменения?

Comment: @Эникейщик в своем конечно. Просто нужно некоторые элементы рекламы с которыми adblock не справляется и чтобы изменения остались после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: Заблокировать? Можно вручную в фильтр внести.

Comment: @Эникейщик это только пример, так возможно ли такое сделать?

Comment: @Cristian на сколько я знаю (могу ошибаться), изменения HTML никак не сохранить, можно только добавлять свои CSS-стили (например скрывать блоки), а манипулировать DOM можно только через JS. Для этого есть специальные расширения для браузера. В каком браузере необходимо "сохранить измененеия"?

Comment: Еще можно (наверное) userContent.css и user.js в фаерфоксе настроить (только не знаю как).

Comment: @RTK Chrome, можете дать пример расширений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно модифицировать сайты путем добавления пользовательских `CSS` и `JavaScript`.

Как правило для этого требуются браузерные расширения.

Расширение **[Tampermonkey](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey)** позволяет добавлять свои скрипты на `JavaScript` и в них [манипулировать с `DOM`](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document).

- [Tampermonkey для Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=ru)
- [Tampermonkey для Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/)
- [Tampermonkey для MS Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/tampermonkey/9nblggh5162s)

Так же для редактирования страниц подходит **[Stylish](http://userstyles.org/)**, вообще это что-то вроде каталога пользовательских тем для сайтов, но там можно создавать свои темы путем изменения CSS-стилей страниц.

- [Stylish для Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=ru)
- [Stylish для Mozilla Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)